# Free UI templates that works with asp.net MVC and razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, user-interface

I want to find an enterprise UI template which I can use inside my asp.net mvc 4 web applications. Some of the known templates will work well web forms , but I need templates that work with asp.net mvc .
BR

Comment: You mean templates like those found in sites like www.themeforest.net?

Comment: yes I mean the main menu, colour, left 7 right side menus ,etc..

Comment: Creating awesome templates using bootstrap is not a hard job. Check this http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2014/4/blog_template_using_twitter_bootstrap3_part1

Comment: This is a recommendation question and needs to be closed

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend spending $14-18 on a good template from sites like [themeforest](http://www.themeforest.net), [DMartify](http://dmartify.com) Or [wrapbootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/)

They have lots of templates that can be used independently of the server-side technology (php, asp.net, RoR, Django, etc.)

If you cannot spend the money on a template, then checkout the free templates at [Bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) which has some basic (but useful) baseline color theme modifications. Or you can also find [Free Admin Template Download](http://dmartify.com/downloads/karmanta-lite-free-admin-template-download/), Simply use [BootStrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) frameworks to make you own.